show the remote changed or not in windows mingw terminal when using git command
I am using the terminal tool in windows mingw bash terminal. I am develop the same branch with another partner. is it possible to let the terminal git show the remote branch is updated or not? Now when I pushed to remote branch will tell me the remote branch is update, then I have to pull then push. or I run the fetch command to check the remote branch update or not. Sometimes I always forget to pull the newest code from remote branch.

Are you looking for git fetch but automatically?

look like a compare tool automatically that shows new changes happen with server, look like a automatically fetch but did not need to fetch automatically. I just want to know the remote update or not. But there is a problem that the remote branch should keep all time, if the remote branch merge and deleted the original, this also could not work.
